# Using Array Join for String Concatenation

Tags: javascript

Attempting using Array.join for string concatenation, but the following is causing FF to choke:

```
var tmp = ["disco","dance"];
for (i = 0; i<tmp.length; i++) {
  tmp.push(piece);
  alert(tmp[i]);
}
str = tmp.join(''); 
return str;
```

Would someone enlighten my usage?

Comment: Where is `piece` declared/defined?

Comment: What's the problem?  What error do you get?   What is `str` set to when this is done?

Answer (score 3):

You've got an infinite loop.  Every iteration increases the length of `tmp`, so `i` will never be greater than `tmp.length`.  Maybe this is what you want:

```
var tmp = ["disco","dance"];
var len = tmp.length;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  tmp.push(piece);
  alert(tmp[i]);
}
str = tmp.join(''); 
return str;
```

**Edit:** Or if `piece` doesn't really mean anything, just skip the for loop altogether:

```
var tmp = ["disco","dance"];
str = tmp.join(''); 
return str;
```

Comment: Was my interpretation of the following example in err? http://aymanh.com/9-javascript-tips-you-may-not-know#string-concatenation-vs-arrayjoin

Comment: What is `piece` and where does it come from?  The example shown demonstrates building up a string into an Array and then joining it.  But, it doesn't show where the elements of the array should come from - that part is left to you and your specific needs.  If you already have an array of strings, there is no need for a `for` loop, you can just call `.join()` on your array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the loop. This, however, works:

```
var tmp = ["disco","dance"];
var str = tmp.join(''); 
return str; // Returns "discodance"
```

...which is just your original code without the loop. I suspect any trouble that you're having has to do with that loop.